# Returning pointer on class member from const member function

Tags: c++, c++11

Are these definitions of `pointer()` equal?

```
class Example
{
public:
    AnotherClass* const pointer() const;
    AnotherClass* pointer() const;


private:
    AnotherClass* m_pointer;
}
```

Does it guarantee me what somebody can't change m_pointer memory pointed to?

Comment: Do you want the member variable `m_pointer` to remain unchanged, or the memory pointed to?

Comment: Memory pointed to. Thanks, I asked no exact question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two overloads for `pointer` only differ in the return type. Your C++ compiler will not accept that, this is an error.

Assuming that pointer() just returns m_pointer:

The declaration `AnotherClass* pointer() const;` would expose the value of m_pointer. Users of the class would not be able to change m_pointer, but they could change the object that m_pointer points to.

The declaration `AnotherClass* const pointer() const;` is quite similar to `AnotherClass* pointer() const;` but the value returned (the temporary pointer) is const. This declaration does not really make sense because you already can't change the return value in the first declaration. You can't write `example.pointer() = nullptr` in either cases. And when you assign the return value to a variable like in `p = example.pointer()` it makes no difference if the return value of pointer() is const or not.

The declarations `const AnotherClass* pointer() const;` and `AnotherClass const * pointer() const;` would expose the value of m_pointer. Users of the class would not be able to change m_pointer, and they would not be able to change the object that m_pointer points to.

Comment: Is it analogue this:

int* const and
int const* ?

Comment: @Eugene Sorry, I made a mistake. I now updated my answer. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

You need the return type for the first method to be one of these:

```
    AnotherClass const * pointer() const;
```

or

```
    const AnotherClass* pointer() const;
```

What you have done is return a **const pointer** to a **non-const object**.

What you want is a **non-const pointer** to a **const object**.

Also, to follow the typical practice your second method should not be const.

```
    AnotherClass* pointer();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider here:

**What is `const`: the pointer or the pointee?**

Let's see the differences between these different declarations.

```
int x, y;

int       *       p = &x; // 0
const int *       p = &x; // 1
int const *       p = &x; // 2
int       * const p = &x; // 3
const int * const p = &x; // 4
int const * const p = &x; // 5
```

(0) means that `p` can change (`p = &y;` is OK) and what it points to (`x`) can be changed via `p` (`*p = y;` is OK).

(1) and (2) are equivalent and mean that `p` can change (`p = &y;` is OK) and what it points to (`x`) cannot be changed via `p` (`*p = y;` is an error).

(3) means that `p` cannot change (`p = &y;` is an error) and what it points to (`x`) can be changed via `p` (`*p = y;` is OK)

(4) and (5) are equivalent and mean that `p` cannot change (`p = &y;` is an error) and what it points to (`x`) cannot be changed via `p` (`*p = y;` is an error).

An easy way to remember this is looking at the `*` and think that it separates the objects **constness**, that is,

(a) a `const` before `*` (e.g. `const int * [...]` or `int const * [...]`) means the pointed object (of type `int`) is `const`; and

(b) a `const` after `*` (e.g. `[...] * const p [...];`) means that the pointer is `const` and cannot be changed.

**What happens if a function returns a `const` object**?

Consider:

```
class some_class;

const some_class a(); // equivalent to 'some_class const a();'
      someclass  b();

const int        c(); // equivalent to 'int const c();'
      int        d();
```

Then, (assuming `some_class` has an accessible assignment operator) we have:

```
some_class x;

a() = x; // illegal : the returned object is const
b() = x; // OK      : the returned object is not const
```

It's natural to believe that `c()` and `d()` behave the same but this is **not** the case:

```
c() = 0; // illegal
d() = 0; // also illegal!!!
```

The reason is that if a function returns a fundamental type (e.g. `int`, `bool`, `char`, any pointer type, ...) then the returned object cannot be assigned to. Therefore,
**returning a `const` object of fundamental type behaves the same as to returning a non-const one**.

**What about overloading on the return type?**

Consider

```
int    f(); // first  overload.
double f(); // second overload.
```

This is illegal. We cannot overload on the return type only. One reason is that we can always ignore the object returned by a function. For instance, if overloading on the return type was allowed, then which overload of `f` would be called below?

```
int main() {
    f(); // which f?
    return 0;
}
```

**Answering the question...**

Consider the first declaration

```
AnotherClass* const pointer() const;
```

From what we have seen, this means that `pointer()` returns a `const` object of type `AnotherClass*` (a pointer type). Since a pointer type is a fundamental type, the function `pointer` above behaves the same as if it was declared as

```
AnotherClass* pointer() const;
```

which is the second overload. This is the first reason why having these two overloads doesn't make sense. But this is just a weak reason compared to the one that follows.

When I say "behaves the same" I don't mean "equivalent". The return type of the two overloads are different. As we have seen, we cannot overload on the return type only. This is illegal and the code doesn't compile.

> > Does it guarantee me what somebody can't change m_pointer memory pointed to?

No, again, both overloads behave the same and return a pointer to an object that can be changed via this pointer. What you want is this:

```
   const AnotherClass* pointer() const { return m_pointer; }
// or
// AnotherClass const* pointer() const { return m_pointer; }
```

Notice the `const` at the left of `*`.

Comment: A very in depth explanation of const, surprised you never mention the right-to-left reading order convention.